# Poor accuracy with a keras neural network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I've been working with keras lately and have created a neural network. When I train this, I get an accurac of < 10%. I have changed the number of layers, used different optimizers, different batch_sizes and epochs.
My data is normalized and therefore I don't know where the problem could be.

What I've been trying to do so far:
Change of the number of layers, optimizer, loss, epochs, batch_size

```
# Create Model
model  = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(18, input_shape=(22,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax'))

X_training, X_test = X[:data_size], X[data_size:]
Y_training, Y_test = Y[:data_size], Y[data_size:]

# Compile Model
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_training, Y_training, epochs=100, batch_size=1000)

# Evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))


Epoch 80/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7351 - acc: 0.0800
Epoch 81/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7348 - acc: 0.0806
Epoch 82/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 5us/step - loss: 6.7347 - acc: 0.0815
Epoch 83/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 5us/step - loss: 6.7344 - acc: 0.0803
Epoch 84/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 5us/step - loss: 6.7344 - acc: 0.0812
Epoch 85/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7340 - acc: 0.0807
Epoch 86/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7339 - acc: 0.0810
Epoch 87/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7337 - acc: 0.0809
Epoch 88/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7335 - acc: 0.0820
Epoch 89/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7333 - acc: 0.0815
Epoch 90/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 5us/step - loss: 6.7331 - acc: 0.0815
Epoch 91/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 5us/step - loss: 6.7329 - acc: 0.0812
Epoch 92/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 5us/step - loss: 6.7329 - acc: 0.0817
Epoch 93/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7326 - acc: 0.0825
Epoch 94/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7325 - acc: 0.0822
Epoch 95/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7325 - acc: 0.0820
Epoch 96/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7322 - acc: 0.0822
Epoch 97/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7320 - acc: 0.0816
Epoch 98/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 5us/step - loss: 6.7319 - acc: 0.0818
Epoch 99/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 5us/step - loss: 6.7317 - acc: 0.0829
Epoch 100/100
156183/156183 [==============================] - 1s 4us/step - loss: 6.7316 - acc: 0.0838
39046/39046 [==============================] - 1s 23us/step

acc: 7.84%


Input: [ 9.11310000e+04 -9.36427789e-02  6.47541209e-01  7.56254860e-01
  6.56986599e-01  7.53902254e-01  9.12945251e-01  4.08082062e-01
  1.41120008e-01 -9.89992497e-01  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]

Expected output / Target: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

how can I achieve a higher accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use `categorical_crossentropy` with a sigmoid activation at the output, use softmax in this case.

Also prefer relu over sigmoid for hidden layers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But the accuracy is still below 10%.
Can I still improve this model or should I check the input data again (although I currently don't know where exactly I should start with the data)?

Comment: @madimo What is the task? Classification? Please add more information about your data and the task.

Comment: Input: normalized longitude and latitude (in 3 dimensions - x,y,z), normalized month, hour, day, and normalized information about a car: [-0.05189977376855792, -0.5532824069711391, -0.8313753614457162, 0.9893582466233818, -0.14550003380861354, -0.7509872467716762, 0.6603167082440802, -0.7568024953079282, -0.6536436208636119, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, ...]

Output: kind, category, type (and every output attributes has different characteristics.

Comment: I have added the expected output and the input